# Unable to use append/appendto/innerhtml or any other to add input box to parent div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the case of type textbox the appendTo does not seem to work.(Why??)
The append code works elsewhere and

```
 if($('#'+json.id).length)
```

is also true but does not show up in the html.
Iv been at this two days :(

Here's the relevant part of my js code

```
switch (json.type) {

    case "container":
        $('<div id=' + json.id + '/>').appendTo('#' + parent_id);
        $('#' + json.id).css({
            // container styling
        });
        break;

    case "text":
       $('#' + parent_id).text(json.value);
        var j = document.createElement('input');
        j.id = "LAPD";
        j.value = "LAPD"
        $(j).appendTo("#"+parent_id);
        break;

    case "image":
        $('<img id=' + json.id + ' src=' + json.value + '/>').appendTo('#' + parent_id);
        break;

    case "textbox":
        var j = document.createElement('input');
        j.id = json.id;
        j.type = 'text';
        $(j).appendTo("#"+parent_id);
        if($('#'+json.id).length){
            console.log("exists");
            }
        else{
            console.log("doesnt");
            }
        break;
}
```

The generated html

```
< body >
< div id = "page" >
    < div id = "id1" > hello world < input id = "LAPD" > < /div>
< /div>
< /body>
```

the input with id="LAPD" is generated from the case:"text"

Comment: You'll need to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Fundamentally, the relevant part of the above works: http://jsbin.com/semetezewu/1

Comment: looks fine - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9wovxxt/1/ - look at your css rule

Comment: Thank you for the MCVE heads up! new guy here. But its not working for me. Any ideas why? (working on the mcve meanwhile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the problem after some debugging. The input box does get appended to the html but the problem was arising due to the code to add text

```
   $('#' + parent_id).text(json.value);
```

This was replacing the entire content of the parent div with the text provided instead of appending it to the current content, as i had expected it to be.